# Getting nested named results from pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am modifying the pyparsing fourFn example to accept variables. Evaluation already works, now I want to be able to parse a string and output a list of required variables. Here's how I would like it to work:

```py
from my_module.parser import FormulaParser

formula = '(x + y) * z'
fp = FormulaParser()
parser.get_variables
# => ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I've added a `set_results_name` call like so:
`ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_$").set_results_name('identifier', list_all_matches=True)`

Now this works when the formula doesn't contain any nesting:

```py
>>> formula = 'x * y + z'
>>> res = fp.parse_string(formula)
>>> res.identifier
ParseResults(['x', 'y', 'z'], {})
```

But I can't figure out how to get at the nested results:

```py
>>> formula = '(x * y - (a/b)) + z'
>>> res = fp.parse_string(formula)
>>> res.identifier
ParseResults(['z'], {})
>>> print(res.dump())
[['x', '*', 'y', '-', ['a', '/', 'b']], '+', 'z']
- identifier: ['z']
[0]:
  ['x', '*', 'y', '-', ['a', '/', 'b']]
  - identifier: ['x', 'y']
  [0]:
    x
  [1]:
    *
  [2]:
    y
  [3]:
    -
  [4]:
    ['a', '/', 'b']
    - identifier: ['a', 'b']
[1]:
  +
[2]:
  z
>>>
```

I see that all the variables are there at different levels. I could brute-force iterating over everything but that would be duplicating the parsers effort.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but `scan_string` sort of works:

```
>>> from pyparsing import alphas, alphanums
>>> identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_$")
>>> formula = '(a * sin(x + y)) / (galaxy - 3)'
>>> myvars = [var[0][0] for var in identifier.scan_string(formula)]
>>> myvars
['a', 'sin', 'x', 'y', 'galaxy']
```

Problems with this approach:

- the `[0][0]` is a bit ugly
- 'PI' isn't excluded. e and pi are defined in the grammar as caseless keywords. `parse_string` correctly excludes them from `identifier`